# C# - Trouble adding attachments to outlook email using different buttons

Tags: c#, outlook, attachment

I'm making a simple Outlook draft generator. It works fine, but I'm trying to add attachments via a browse button, but I can't figure it out. I need an OpenFileDialog object to use the Attachments.Add method to add it to the email, but I'm losing the reference to the OpenFileDialog object because it only exists in the AddAttachment() function.

```
OpenFileDialog attachment = new OpenFileDialog();

        attachment.Title = "Select files to attach";
        attachment.ShowDialog();

            if (attachment.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment.FileName, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, attachment.FileName);
        }
```

This works, but it's in the same function as my CreateMailItem() function, which means it will always open the File Dialog, have you clicked in the browse button or not.

```
 private void CreateMailItem()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        mail.Subject = "";
        mail.To = "";
        mail.CC = "";
        mail.Body = "";
        mail.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
        mail.Display(false);
```

This function is followed by the OpenFileDialog part.
I want to add the OpenFileDialog part to a button, then pass the OpenFileDialog object instance FileName to the mail.Attachment.Add() method, but the mail object exists only in the CreateMailItem() method. After all is said and done, I want to generate the email draft with the attachments with the CreateMailItem() method. Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to declare an instance of the `OpenFileDialog` class at the global scope and check whether the `FileName` property is initialized or not.

Or simply you can pass an instance of the MailItem class to the AddAttachment method:

```
public void AddAttachment(MailItem mail)
{
    OpenFileDialog attachment = new OpenFileDialog();

    attachment.Title = "Select files to attach";
    attachment.ShowDialog();

        if (attachment.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment.FileName, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, attachment.FileName);
    }
 }

 private void CreateMailItem()
 {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

    mail.Subject = "";
    mail.To = "";
    mail.CC = "";
    mail.Body = "";
    mail.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;

    AddAttachment(mail);

    mail.Display(false);
 }
```

Finally, don't use multiple dots in the single line of code. I always recommend breaking the chain of property and method calls and declaring them on a separate lines. It allows to release underlying COM objects instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

Comment: I tried doing that earlier, the problem is that it calls the method AddAttachment() inside the method CreateMailItem(), so it will always pop up the OpenFileDialog, when I actually want it to pop up only when I click in my browse button.

Comment: Do you need to attach the selected file to multiple emails?

Comment: Nope, just to this email I'm creating. All I need is a browse button function to remember the files I want to add to the email, and then add them when I click the "generate email button".

Comment: My form is pretty basic: it has some text fields which are passed to the MailItem object attributes (CC, Subject, and so on). Then, I have a browse button to add attachments and then I have a "Generate email" button. The correct order would be to click on browse, set the attachments you want to add, then click on the "Generate email" button, which will create my Mail object. Problem is: the Mail object doesn't exist in my addAttachment() method (which is in my browse button), and I'm having trouble with that. Hope it's clearer now!